# What wise choice does Varys intend to make?

Tags: dialogue, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* s08e04 we see Varys and Tyrion having a conversation about who would be the best heir for the Iron Throne where Varys seems to try to conspire against Daenerys. Here are the last phrases of their dialogue:

> Varys: You know where my loyalty stands. You know I will never betray the realm.
>
> Tyrion: What is the realm? Vast continent home to millions of people most of whom don't care who sits on the Iron Throne.
>
> Varys: Millions of people. Many of them will die if the wrong person sits on that throne. We don't know their names but they are just as real as you and I. They deserve to live. They deserve food for their children. **I will act in their interest no matter the personal cost.**
>
> Tyrion: **So what happens to her? Please ... don't ...**
>
> Varys: **I have spoken as honestly as I can. Each of us has a choice to make. I pray we choose wisely.**

What does Varys's last words exactly mean? What is he planning to do? Does he imply something specific?

Comment: This means that the two last episode will be about... game of thrones.

Comment: You also bolded the mention of "personal cost" so presumably also include asking what that is - I don't think the present answers discuss that, unfortunately (it has been discussed explicitly in the show)

Comment: Basically means he is gonna betray Danny.

Comment: @pradyot both the answers assume this.  But I assumed a vaguer interpretation - he's stating outright that there *is* going to be a choice to be made.  Within the Danny/Jonny alliance but outside of the insular Northerners no-one has actually talked about choosing Jon for the throne.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because any attempt to answer would be pure guesswork, until after future episodes are aired at which point it would be trivial.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Both of the answers are well-documented and answer the question. The question has many aspects and concerns Varys's motivations,goals,intenions and the reasons behind them.

Comment: They're not "documented" at all. No sources whatsoever, just guesswork.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: There are references to the past and statements that support Vary's choice.

Comment: @MJ13 An oblique reference to the spirit of past dialogue is not documentation. A well-documented answer would include specific quotes, and extrapolations from them along with explanations of why those extrapolations are reliable, along with citations. The current answers are only guesses based on vagaries.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If Jon is to be put on the throne the only option for Daenerys is to kill her, because she's too dangerous with her dragons and people who would continue to support her, which could well include Jon. So the insinuation and what Tyrion is pleading against is that Varys would try to assassinate her.

Comment: Some good material over here: https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/2019/05/231839/will-varys-kill-daenerys-game-of-thrones-season-8-episode-4

Comment: About that plural on "dragons"... ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Lord Varys wants to see people happy and is thinking about normal people.

Daenerys kind of reminds him of the Mad King, who wanted to burn everything and everyone, Cersei burnt the Sept, Joffrey was crazy.

Daenerys could burn the place down and lots of innocent people will die. However, Varys is hinting to Tyrion that Jon Snow would be a better king (after finding out he's a Targaryen) because he is a more rational person, based on his previous experiences beyond the Wall, Castle Black, Hardhome, as King in the North, and would care about the people, and would be a better king.

The choice is to choose who sits on the throne, and Varys has made his decision and it's not Daenerys.

Comment: Yeah this is what he actually tells to Tyrion during their discussion. However the question is what is he planning to do to make that happen? Which are his intentions for the future?

Comment: That part is still unknown for now.

Comment: @StackOne is correct, there's no indication that Varys has made a final decision already. He says "each of us has a choice to make", not "one of us has a choice to make".

Answer (score -3):

Varys is going to reveal the information that Jon is a Targaryen and he should sit on the Iron Throne.

Update.
Hi tried, actually
[image]

Comment: It seems more likely that Varys is going to attempt to assassinate Dany so there isn't any competition for Jon. In fact Tyrion's reaction and the fact Varys already considers it information backs this up.

Comment: So, actually hi tried.
https://i.imgur.com/vhjoH8h.png